# User's contact number from twitter after login with twitter, in ios app

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

Is it feasible to get user's contact/mobile number after logging in with twitter? If yes,  Is there any case that we can’t get mobile number example if user set mobile number secured or private or user didn’t enter mobile number at the time of twitter registration.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: No we can get only `email id` of the twitter user.

Comment: @Karthick: Thanks for your reply. is there any official doc regarding this?

Comment: Yes in `twitterKit` there is a method to get the user `EmailId` but nothing is there for getting the mobile number.

Comment: Documentation for the email feature is here: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/twitter/log-in-with-twitter.html#request-user-email-address